# What are sites for Hadoop Best practices

Tags: hadoop

What are sites for Hadoop Best practice , Not the Books where I can get the step by step process to create new projects and small examples . I am not able to find a single site like this , please share.

Comment: The required VM , cluste everything is well setup in my machine , i just need the source code with Java . For example sites like "http://www.kodejava.org/" for java where they have written all the source code . So like this is there any site which provides the examples . I am able to search the code but i not able to find the perfect one

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Best site for Hadoop Practical , Like codding stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422096/what-is-the-best-site-for-hadoop-practical-like-codding-stuff)

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome article from yahoo developers on [Apache Hadoop: Best Practices and Anti-Patterns](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2010/08/apache_hadoop_best_practices_a/)

Comment: The required VM , cluste everything is well setup in my machine , i just need the source code with Java . For example sites like "kodejava.org/"; for java where they have written all the source code . So like this is there any site which provides the examples . I am able to search the code but i not able to find the perfect one

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not something one single application instead it is a distributed processing framework which is used by several applications which sits top of this framework. Pig, Hive, HBase, Cassandra, etc are few of many such application designed for specific requirement. Underneath all of these application consume Hadoop framework which mainly consist of distributed file system (HDFS) and distributed processing (MapReduce).

Technically when you have a bare minimum Hadoop cluster (HDFS + MapReduce only) you can start writing MapReduce based applications (in Java or other languages are supported through Hadoop Streaming) to process some data.

What you could do is first download a pre-build/configured Hadoop virtual Image from Cloudera or Hortonworks distribution and get it running in your machine. After that start learning writing MapReduce jobs in Java and run  in your virtual machine.

Here is the URL to [download Cloudera Hadoop Distribution VM](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Demo+VMs)

Here is the [link](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/DOC/Hadoop+Tutorial) to learn writing simplest wordcount job.

Comment: The required VM , cluste everything is well setup in my machine , i just need the source code with Java . For example sites like "kodejava.org/"; for java where they have written all the source code . So like this is there any site which provides the examples . I am able to search the code but i not able to find the perfect one , please help

Comment: Check this out for MapReduce: http://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/confused-about-mapreduce/

Comment: Yes this is the site , is there any other site also wher i can find java hadoop codding

Comment: at least you have a point to start, so stop asking more and learn from what you have... also please ask specific question not a general question.. no body have time here to search internet for you.